# Serial port write and read during same method

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I am developing an electric test software that must be automated.
I'm working with with a PA4400A from PowerTek and I'm communicating with him using RS-232.
If I send a command using a button then, after about 4 seconds if I'm reading it with another button, the answer is full and correct. If I am placing the read and write command inside the button method, even with 10 seconds delay between write and read, I will get no answer.

Variable declarations:

```
QTime timp2;
QSerialPort port_PA;
```

Port initialization:

```
port_PA.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud19200);
port_PA.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
port_PA.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
port_PA.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
port_PA.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
port_PA.setPortName("ttyUSB0");
port_PA.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

Button method:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

QString ans;
timp2.start();
while(ans.size() == 0 && timp2.elapsed()<10000)
{
    ui->label_2->setText(timp2.toString());
    ans.append(port_PA.readAll());
}
qDebug()<<ans;
ans.clear();
qDebug()<<ans.size();
port_PA.write(cxz);
timp2.restart();
while(timp2.elapsed()<5000)
{

}
timp2.restart();
while(ans.size() == 0 && timp2.elapsed()<10000)
{
    //qDebug()<<timp2.elapsed();
    ans.append(port_PA.readAll());
}
port_PA.write(cxz);
qDebug()<<ans;
}
```

Where cxz is a QByteArray that holds into it the command for the machine.
ans value while using the button: " 00.00E+0 <(END OF DATA)>"
ans value while using the above method: ""

I am only looking for the reason of this happening and a possible solution to it.
Thanks for help.

Comment: have you tried using event driven approach of the serial port? you don't need to worry about timing as you will be notified of data availability.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror Actually, I haven't tried that. I will give it a shot and I will let you know